# Battlefield 3 negative skill level?

Tags: battlefield-3

Does anyone know why, even after finishing a multiplayer round and earning the MVP2 ribbon, I get a negative skill level? These are the stats from this round that i pulled from Battlelog.

```
Skill level -1.76
Kills 9
Deaths 8
K/D Ratio 1.125 
Kill Assists 2 
Vehicles Destroyed 2
Award Score 1100
Squad Score 20
Team Score 1350
Objective Score 50
General Score 2023
Unlock Score 200
Support Score 3513
Bonus Score 70
Combat Score 3513
Total Score 4813
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It goes based on your placement in relation to others. If you were MVP 2, and your skill level before this match was 100, but everyone else in your server was skill level 0, and you only barely beat them, then your skill will still go down.

Conversely, you can just barely come last, but if your skill was 0 and everyone else had 1000, then you'll go up.

Answer (score 6):

Skill level has been said to be based on [Elo rating system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system). Exact algorithm is not disclosed, but from my experience it seems, that it takes in account kills, rather than score (unlike MVP badges which are score only).

You gain/loose SL each time you kill/die. If you kill highly skilled player, you gain lot of skill points, if you kill low skilled player you gain few. On the other hand if you get killed by more skilled player, you loose less points, than when killed by low ranked one.

In standard ELO skill level 0 means that you're exactly average. Negative is below average, positive is above average. However, this doesn't seem to be the case in BF3's modified ELO.

Looking at BF3Stats, seems that **median skill level is about 450.**

Comment: Are you sure skill level 0 is average and not 100? I'm pretty lousy and my skill level is almost never a negative value.