# How is skill level calculated in Battlelog?

Tags: battlefield-3

After a match, I usually look in Battlelog match resume to observe my results, together with those of my teammates and opponents.

One question came to my mind: how is skill level calculated?

In fact, while you can see my battle stats with a K/D outcome of 14/13 and 12% accuracy report a skill level of 13.77, the top player from the winning team had a -10.71 skill level with a K/D of 25/14 and a greater accuracy than mine.

How come?

[image: Stats for the match]

[image]

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33502/battlefield-3-negative-skill-level

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[From Dice:](http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/forum/threadview/2832654489451569869/)

> This is what determines your skill level on your stats page:
>
> - You gain/loose SL based on every confrontation with another player
> - Killing a highly skilled enemy gives you more points than killing
>     someone less skilled
> - Points are not transferred from a player to another, they are simply
>     added/subtracted based on the encounter and the SL of both parts
>     (thus, after an encounter, one part may go up 50 points while the
>     other loses only 20)
> - The SL is used for matchmaking

Skill level fluctuates so much, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: I second that. Skill Level is of no importance.

Comment: Third that. I've seen my skill level (total, not just round) fluctuate by hundreds just from two rounds played. The global skill level is therefore pretty useless in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a little bit of info to Foxtrot's answer, my biggest gain in one match was 199.04, my biggest loss -192.84. This graph shows the fluctuation as compared to K/D, SPM, and W/L. As you can see, there is really no correlation. In my opinion, SPM when taken with a decent K/D is a much better measure of skill.

[image]

Also, for example, here are some numbers from my clan:

K/D W/L SPM Skill

0.97 0.86 248 274

1.28 1.69 304 150

1.49 1.43 515 102

0.81 1.80 250 239

1.17 1.12 334 -165

Comment: Nice example to add.

Comment: I agree that you should take Skill Level with a certain 'pinch of salt', but I'm not sure KDR is what you should be looking at either. The problem with concentrating on KDR is that it encourages selfish play: Do I join in the attack/defence of the flag, or sit back at a safer distance? Good players will tend to have a *combination* of better statistics

Comment: @CJM - I didn't say it did, and I have a very good combination (in terms of ranking, my KDR is my worst stat). I was merely comparing skill, SPM, KDR, and W/L to show there does not seem to be a correlation to any of them

Answer (score 1):

The skill level is also based on in-game actions (Capturing/defending, Squad revives/assists etc) Which is why you will sometimes see the player with the most kills have a lower skill ranking.